# Error - No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation

Tags: java, android, android-context

A) Why when i try to run the app i get this error?

My Crash Log Error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must
>   run under a registering instrumentation.
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation
>   registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.java:45)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(InstrumentationRegistry.java:75)
>                                                                                at
>   com.wachipi.challengetv.GuidaTvActivity$GetData.onPreExecute(main.java:76)
>                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:613)
>                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:560)
>                                                                                at com.wachipi.challengetv.GuidaTvActivity.onCreate(main.java:68)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
>
> Unable to start activity ComponentInfojava.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering
>   instrumentation.

What caused that? I'm yet learning and i'll appreciate if you can explain more.

This is my code

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;




import static android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getContext;
import static com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahn.runOnUiThread;



/**
 * Created by GB on 28/03/18.
 */

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    //url per il recupero del JSON
    private static String url = "there is an url trust me. But i need to hide";

    private ListView TodayMenu;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DATA;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toolbar toolbargtv = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbargtv);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbargtv);

        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ViewPager viewer = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewer);
        setupViewPager(viewer);

        TabLayout tabsgtv = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabsgtv);
        tabsgtv.setupWithViewPager(viewer);

        DATA = new ArrayList<>();

        TodayMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.todayMenu);

        new GetData().execute();
    }

    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            //Mostro avviso
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            pDialog.setMessage("Attendi..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            //faccio una richiesta al server e attendo risposta
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url); 
            Log.e("RAW-JSON: ","Retrieve RAW-Json is "+jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String DATESTRING = jsonObj.getString("date");

                    JSONObject DATE = new JSONObject(DATESTRING); //Log.d("STAMPA","DATESTRING"+DATESTRING);

                    //Log.d("PER FAVORE","IERI ERA "+Ieri);
                    //ESTRAGGO E INSERISCO DOVE MI SERVE
                    String Yesterday = DATE.getString("ieri");
                    String Today = DATE.getString("oggi");
                    String Tomorrow = DATE.getString("domani");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Errore nel recupero dati",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //tolgo il caricamento di pDialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new YesterdayFragment(),"" );  //i can set from here the name of tabs but how is the name from by Json?
        adapter.addFragment(new TodayFragment(), "");
        adapter.addFragment(new TomorrowFragment(), "");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already read that but it's not my problem

Comment: than share your whole crash log with question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to use a context in `pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());` but instead of using the context like `this`(activity context) or `getApplicationContext()` you are using an InstrumentationRegistry context, which in your case is not useful because that's not a test, see your import `import static android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getContext;`
Just fix the context to use the right one.

Comment: Ty so much now is work! Any idea for the first question?

And if you want coul you explain me this type of error?

Comment: @Trusted About the error is quiet simple to identify where it was by looking at two things in the error logs: 1st `com.wachipi.challengetv.GuidaTvActivity.onCreate(main.java:68)` which indicates the line where it is starting to happen the issue. And 2nd when you need to pass a Context in any of your classes inside the normal app folder it will never be a context from the InstrumentationRegistry. The InstrumentationRegistry context is only needed in your tests package (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html#getContext()).

Comment: @Trusted About the request for a solution about the dates, you should remove that one from this question, as the question becomes too broad, and make a new question out of it, by also providing more info and why you can't achieve it - as it is now, the question is not specific and it is hard to understand with the little details you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `import static android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getContext;`

then you need to pass the context (using `this` or anything similar) of the activity instead.