# Unable to run test in android application

Tags: java, android, testing

I am trying to run an Instrumentation Test for my android application followiwng a tutorial but unfortunately I keep getting the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.` error. I have added the required dependencies in the gradle file but still can't get it to run. Here is my test file:

```
package com.example.georgek.notekeeper;

import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner;

import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class NoteCreationTest extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<NoteListActivity> mNoteListActivityActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(NoteListActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void createNewNote() {
//        ViewInteraction fabNewNote = onView(withId(R.id.fab));
//        fabNewNote.perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.fab)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.text_note_title)).perform(typeText("Test note title"));
        onView(withId(R.id.text_note_text)).perform(typeText("This is the body of our test note"),
                closeSoftKeyboard());
    }


}
```

And my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.georgek.notekeeper"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0'

}
```

And this is the error message I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
at androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.java:50)
at androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(InstrumentationRegistry.java:101)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.<init>(ActivityTestRule.java:144)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.<init>(ActivityTestRule.java:120)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.<init>(ActivityTestRule.java:103)
at com.example.georgek.notekeeper.NoteCreationTest.<init>(NoteCreationTest.java:23)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2075)
```

Note I have seen the questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957741/android-illegalstateexception-no-instrumentation-registered-must-run-under-a-re) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571367/error-no-instrumentation-registered-must-run-under-a-registering-instrumentat) and both have not helped my situation.

Comment: What do you use to launch your tests?

Comment: An android emulator!

Comment: Do you use gradle commands or android studio running configuration?

Comment: Android studio running configurations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the tutorial you are using is a little bit outdated. For now AndroidX test libs migrated to the `android.support.test`. You need either replace your test runner in gradle to use AndroidX package:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "the.dreams.wind.insect"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
...

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0'

}
```

OR replace your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

define the runner:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

**and** add `androidx.test.ext:junit` to the dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.0.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0"

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.1.0"

    ...
}
```

the dependency is required to replace deprecated class `AndroidJUnit4`.

Comment: I noticed that too but using this method makes it difficult for me to follow the tutorial. I will most likely need this after that tutorial.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen those classes behave merely the same, except some deprecated warnings (eg. `InstumentationRegistry.getContext()`). androidx are just renamed support libraries.